# Need reference of books/papers which deals with Ternary Banach Algebras

Tags: reference-request, banach-spaces, operator-theory

I'm interested in learning about ternary Banach Algebras ( mainly ideal theory and tensor product)

> Can someone please recommend me some papers/ books/ notes which deals with mentioned topics?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: If you won't receive a reply from an expert in the field, then perhaps you might find useful the book by Hanhce-Olsen and Størmer, titled "Jordan Operator Algebras".